# Recreate curl command that sends JSON as multipart/form-data using Python-Requests

Tags: python, json, curl, python-requests, multipartform-data

I'm trying to create a Python-Requests version of the following curl POST command (which works perfectly and provides the expected response):

```
curl -F 'json={"method":"update_video","params":{"video":{"id":"129263001","itemState":"INACTIVE"},"token":"jCoXH5OAMYQtXm1sg62KAF3ysG90YLagDAdlhg.."}}' https://api.somewebservice.com/services/post
```

Using:

```
curl -v -F 'json={"method":"update_video","params":{"video":{"id":"582984001","itemState":"INACTIVE"},"token":"jCoXH5OAMYQtXm1sg62KAF3ysG90YLagEECDAdlhg.."}}' https://api.somewebservice.com/services/post
```

I get the following (only including output after all the TLS handshakes, server certificate data, etc):

```
....

> POST /services/post HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.41.0
> Host: api.somewebservice.com
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 294
> Expect: 100-continue
> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------871a9aa84d3c0de2
> 
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
< Content-Length: 1228
< Date: Sun, 10 Apr 2016 07:04:00 GMT
< Server: somewebservice
```

Given that the above cURL command works perfectly and given this output here running in verbose mode, am I correct in assuming that what I need to do is take a multi-part/form approach that sends a JSON object in a form if I'm trying to recreate this using Python-Requests?

So far, I've tried:

```
import requests
import json

def deactivate_request():
    url = "https://api.somewebservice.com/services/post"
    headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'text/plain'}
    payload = {"method":"update_video","params":{"video":{"id":"12926301","itemState":"INACTIVE"},"token":"jCoXH5OKAF3ysG90YLagEECTP16uOUSg_fEGDAdlhg.."}}
    r = requests.post(url, json=payload, headers=headers)
    print(r.text)
```

I've tried different variations too, like:

```
    r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
```

or without headers, like this:

```
    r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload))
```

or this:

```
    r = requests.post(url, json=payload)
```

And nothing seems to work, I just keep getting the same error message:

```
{"error": {"name":"MissingJSONError","message":"Could not find JSON-RPC.","code":211}, "result": null, "id": null}
```

The documentation for this web service for that "211" error states that:

***We got a null string for either the json parameter (for a non-multipart post) or the first part of a multipart post.***

What am I doing wrong here in terms of recreating this cURL request using the Requests module? I thought that I could send the payload object as form-encoded data, and it looks like that is what the cURL command is doing with the `-F` argument there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this curl command can be recreated with the following:

```
import requests

    def deactivate_request():
        url = "https://api.somewebservice.com/services/post"
        print url
        #headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer " + token, "Content-Type": "application/json"}
        headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

        print(headers)

        payload = 'json={"method":"update_video", "params":{"video":{"id":"620001", "itemState":"INACTIVE"}, "token":"jCoXH5OAMYQtXm1sg62KAF3yECTP16uOUSg_fEGDAdlhg.."}}'
        # using params instead of data because we are making this POST request by
        # constructing query string URL with key/value pairs in it.

        r = requests.post(url, params=payload, headers=headers)
```

Not quite obvious as the curl command uses `'multipart/form-data'` in its header whereas with the above we're just using `'application/json'`.